# How to make rules for changing parameters

Tags: output-formatting, replacement

I have one boring problem with changing parameters in printing output. If I have 
equation

```
    eq = Plus[Times[a1,Derivative[2,0][q2][x,y]],Times[a2,Derivative[3,1][q1][x,y]]];
```

I want to replace all derivatives with new variables, for example this

```
      Derivative[2, 0][q2][x, y]
```

I want to replace it with $C_{\mathrm{q2}}^{2,0}$ and for all of them on the same way to get `eq` output automatically in this form

$\mathrm{a1}\,C_{\mathrm{q2}}^{2,0}+\mathrm{a2}\,C_{\mathrm{q1}}^{3,1}$

Comment: Check [`SubsuperscriptBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SubsuperscriptBox.html).

Comment: there is not explanation hoe to change them automatically

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by *changing parameters*. But you might also be interested in [RuleDelayed (:>)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this might be what you're looking for:

```
eq /. Derivative[n__][q_][__] :>
            RawBoxes[
                 SubsuperscriptBox["C",
                                   ToString[q],
                                   RowBox[Riffle[{n}, ","]]
              ]]
```

[image: formatted box]

Please note the using of `SubsuperscriptBox` and `RawBoxes`, which will prevent superscript being evaluated as `Power`.