# Applying rules with functions to expressions with derivatives

Tags: replacement

I have a function that I want to see applied, potentially within a derivative.  The use of delayed vs. non-delayed rules seems irrelevant.  See the following:

```
f$sub = {f[c_] :> a c};

f[c] //. f$sub;

q (f[c])^2 //. f$sub;

D[f[c], c] //. f$sub;

D[f[c] //. f$sub, c] //. f$sub;

(*The following is a rough reason of why I wanted rules *)
g$sub = {g[a] :> a + f[c] }

g2$sub = {g2[a] :> a + D[f[c], c] }

g[a] //. g$sub (* Don't want f sub'd, want to see it left with the function *)

g[a] //. Union[g$sub, f$sub] (* Want f$sub used to simplify things *)

f$alt$sub = {f[c_] :> 2 a c};

g2[a] //. Union[g2$sub, f$alt$sub ](* What does it look like with the alternative *)
```

Ideally, I would want to see the output as `a c`, `q (a c)^2`, `a`.  The last doesn't work, presumably becomes `FullForm@D[f[c],c]` is `Derivative[1][f][c]` which doesn't match the pattern.  Are there any easy tricks to get the substitution to respect derivatives?  My first attempt of changing the rule to `fsub = {f[c_] :> a c, Derivative[1][f][c_] :>  D[f[c], c]}` didn't seem to do anything (delayed or not).

Comment: May be this `D[f[c] //. fsub, c] //. fsub`.Raise it to power or anything else to see if its done or not.

Comment: That does it for this example.  The problem is that in reality I am applying this substitution to pretty complicated expressions where I want to write out the expression properly and then do the substitution.  (e.g. something like `exp = D[f[c],c] + a c / (D[f[c],c,c]^2); exp //. fsub;`  That approach would force me to re-write  the entire expression with the substitutions embedded throughout.

Comment: Instead of using `Replace` simply use function `f[c_] := a c`, you will get same result.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [(7876)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7876/121), [(6089)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6089/121), [(27230)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27230/121) -- have you looked at these?

Comment: @Blackbird I went ahead and posted it.  If you choose to post I will delete mine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : You have a permanent go ahead from my side always :)

Comment: @Blackbird Alright then.

Comment: See my edits to the question.  It definitely solves the exact problem, but I left off part of the motivation for using rules.

Comment: I checked the other links.  They look related, but I can't figure out how to apply them to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possibility:

```
Clear[f,g,a,c]

f$sub = {f :> Function[{c}, a c]};

f[c] //. f$sub

(* ==> a c *)

q (f[c])^2 //. f$sub

(* ==> a^2 c^2 q *)

D[f[c], c] //. f$sub

(* ==> a *)

D[f[c] //. f$sub, c] //. f$sub

(* ==> a *)

g$sub = {g :> Function[a, a + f[c]]};

g2$sub = {g2 :> Function[a, a + D[f[c], c]]};

g[a] //. g$sub (*Don't want f sub'd,want to see it left with the \
function*)

(* ==> a + f[c] *)

g[a] //. 
 Union[g$sub, f$sub] (*Want f$sub used to simplify things*)

(* ==> a + a c *)
```

The only difference to your substitution rules is that I substitute only the `Head` and replace it by a `Function` containing the desired form. This works with `Derivative` because in the `FullForm` of an expression such as `f'[x]` you find the `f` by itself, and the replacement rule won't match it if that rule involves `f[c_]` as a pattern.

What happens behind the scenes in your derivative example is that `D[...]` gets converted into `Derivative`, which can cause consternation if you make patterns that are intended to match the function in `D[f[x],x]` because `f[x]` never appears in that form there.

Comment: Very interesting.  Assuming that I don't really need pattern matching, are there any tradeoffs or gotchas in defining with functions in the `Function[...]` way compared to the more canonical method?  Extra credit if you can combine the parameter with my other outstanding question( http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32648/how-to-define-a-function-of-zbar-etc).  e.g. `Function[{a, b[bar]}, a + 2 b[bar]]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. This post is about "applying rules", isn't it? When you say you "don't really need pattern matching", how is that related to the question? What do you mean by "more canonical"?

Comment: I guess canonical is a little ambiguous.  I guess what I mean is the `f[x_]:= 2 x` style definition as slightly more canonical than `f := Function[x, 2 x]`and allowing for pattern matching (e.g. `f[x_Integer]:= 3 x` can be added for a specialization).  As I don't need any of that fancy pattern matching but am unfamiliar with using functions with formal parameters, I guess I am asking whether their are a bunch of other gotchas when using `Function[{x}, ...]`

Comment: I can't think of any general way of answering the "gotcha" question, but in the context of your question, there is no gotcha since my approach produces the output you want for each of the examples you gave, using rules as stated in the question title.

Answer (score 3):

[Blackbird](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1561/blackbird) suggested defining a function `f` rather than using a replacement rule.
Indeed, this appears to work as requested:

```
fn = Block[{f}, f[c_] := a c; #] &;

f[c]       // fn
q (f[c])^2 // fn
D[f[c], c] // fn
```

> ```
> a c
>
> a^2 c^2 q
>
> a
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  Take a look at my updated use case to explain why I want to use rules (e.g. display without the substitution, use alternative substitutions, etc.)

Comment: @jlperla I need to leave soon.  From a quick glance I think you could still use the method above, you just need a method to convert rules to definitions.  Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Sure.  I couldn't figure out how to do the things above without using rules, but if I can fulfill the stated requirements in any way, then I am happy.

Comment: Mr wizard, what do you think of the solution by @Jens? Is it more general than this approach