# How to change symbols in differential equation with a single rule?

Tags: differential-equations, replacement, rule

#### Problem

Suppose I have a differential equation such as

$\qquad f'(x)+f(x)=0$

and I want to change it into

$\qquad  y'+y=0$

#### My Method

Using `rule = f[x] -> y`, I got `y + f'[x] == 0`

#### Question

How do I get `y' + y == 0` with a single rule. I don't want to use the literal and verbose `rule1 = {f[x] -> y, f'[x] -> y'}`?

Comment: Not a sigle rule so doesn't count :) `f'[x] + f[x] == 0 /. {f[___] -> y, 
  Derivative[n__][f][___] :> Derivative[n][y]}`

Comment: Related: [(32651)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32651/121)

Comment: @halirutan - I agree and have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question suggests that you are not aware that `f[x]` and `f'[x]` have very different internal representations.

```
FullForm/@{f[x],f'[x]}
(* {f[x],Derivative[1][f][x]} *)
```

Matching those two expressions in a single rule would lead to nothing beautiful. The suggestion of Kuba is indeed a very good one because you only have to write two rules to match `f` and *all* its derivatives:

```
{f[x],f'[x],f'''[x]} /. {f[_]->y,Derivative[n__][f][_]:>Derivative[n][y]}
(* {y,y^′,y^(3)} *)
```

Comment: Your answer is what I need! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with halirutan that doing this with a single rule is not a great idea, because the result is likely to be gross and confusing. However, in order to **prove** that it's on the yucky side, I'm going to show the best way I could figure out how to do it. I make no promises about its robustness, but it at least seems to handle the most obvious wrinkles OK.

First, I match on heads applied to `f`, and use `Alternatives` to get either a `Derivative` of `f` or `f` itself. Once you have that match with `Alternatives`, you can do almost anything with it on the right-hand side. I don't think any of the choices are aesthetically pleasing, but here's one that I think is awful in a kind of fun way.

```
In[1]:= rule = h : (_Derivative[f] | f)[x] :>
           FirstCase[h, _Derivative, Identity, {2}, Heads -> True]@y;

In[2]:= 2*f[x] + g'[z]*f''[x] /. rule
Out[2]= 2 y + y'' g'[z]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  f'[x] + f[x] /. f -> (y) /. a_[_] -> a

(*  y + Derivative[1][y]  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: It's tricky, however it works in this simple situation.

Comment: @PureLine The only "tricky" thing here is that `y` stays in brackets. All the rest is trivial, is not it?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Very bad idea if there is anything more in the expression: `Log[f'[x] + f[x]] /. f -> (y) /. a_[_] -> a`

Comment: @halirutan Right, a very bad idea, this is much better `Log[f'[x] + f[x] /. f -> (y) /. a_[_] -> a] ` giving `Log[y + Derivative[1][y]] `. Have fun!